# Multiple Inner Joins in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to do multiple inner joins with MySQL but I keep getting the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'on codes.code = votes.code ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 0, 30' at
>   line 2

```
SELECT * FROM codes 
INNER JOIN user ON codes.userid = user.gid
INNER JOIN on codes.code = votes.code
ORDER BY date desc
```

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ya missed the table name in the second join:

```
SELECT * FROM codes 
INNER JOIN user ON codes.userid = user.gid
INNER JOIN votes on codes.code = votes.code
ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: @K20GH, no problem, happens to everyone every once in a while :)